# Cannot recover previously bought app

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios-appstore

I've bought in 2010 the app "GoodReader" for iPhone and I would like to restore it to my iPad. However I cannot see it in my list of purchased apps in iTunes (although many others do show up).

Any idea why is so, and how to make it appear in my list?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the developers have decided to isolate each new version to be an app in its own right.
Owning v1, 2 or 3 does not automatically get you v4.

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/goodreader/id777310222?mt=8

> The amazing 4th edition of GoodReader® app is a universal app for all your iOS devices.
>
> This version is a further step in development of our original groundbreaking, best-in-class GoodReader app. If you're a user of the old GoodReader app, we welcome you to upgrade to this 4th edition of GoodReader.

This would mean that unless you have a local backup of the app, it would appear it is no longer on the iTunes Store to re-download.